# select * from concat('tab', 'Maintenance Details') in sql

Tags: sql

how to get value from table, where table name is a value from another table and in which i have to concat a string

I tried the below methods

eg:

```
select * from concat('tab', 'Maintenance Details')
```

or

```
select * from (select concat('tab', 'Maintenance Details'));
```

In the above examples 'Maintenance Details' is changed based on its parent query.

what i want to perform is

> select
> (
> select sum(md.fieldname)  from md.tablename
> )
> from `tabMaintenance` md;

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tagging multiple conflicting technologies makes your question unclear and thus *harder* to answer. It is also unlikely to get your question "more views" and likely to have the opposite effect, where only users who know *all* the RDBMS you have (mis)tagged will entertain the question; that is often a very small portion of the user base. Tag spam is far more likely to result in your question receiving downvotes and/or being closed as unclear. Please [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for this. I.e. create the whole SELECT query as a string, which is sent for execution.

Answer (score 0):

You need dynamic sql as exec sp_executesql @sql

Example:

```
declare @sql nvarhcar(3000)
declare @tableName nvarhcar(50) = select tableName from TableA

set @sql = 'select * from '+tableName + 'where conditionhere'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

see more about `sp_executesql` here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I have to perform that in my subquery

for eg:

select 
    (
        select sum(md.fieldname)  from md.tablename 
    )
from `tabMaintenance` md;

Comment: then the whole query should be in that @sql.